# Using SUMIF until last row in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to incorporate a SUMIF formula into my macro. The code in excel looks like this: =SUMIF('WSO Interest' H2:H46, '20140618 Loans' D10, 'WSO Interest' S2:S46)

I set my `dim` as i and lastrow as `integer`
I already set that so that I can find the last row of the column and continue my loop until the last row. 
I also used

```
Sheets("20140618 Loans").Select
Range("A10").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row
```

to find the last row filled with text.

This is what 
I have so far:

```
Range("W10").select
For i = 10 to lastrow
```

SUMIF formula would go here

```
Next i
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is use the SUMIF formula in my macro to start at W10 and keep calculating the SUMIF formula until it reaches the last row. Thanks for the help and feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: do you want to find last cell in the row that is filled or copy the formaula to last cell

Comment: the last cell in the row that is filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Formula` property of a `Range` object to set the formula.

```
Range("W" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF('WSO Interest'!H2:H" & lastrow & _
    ", '20140618 Loans'!D10, 'WSO Interest'!S2:S" & lastrow & ")"
```

The `&` operator is used to concatenate strings together.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. This ends up going all the way down, but I want it to stop at the last row that has text. I did       `Range("a1").Select`
    `Selection.End(xlDown).Select`
    `lastrow = ActiveCell.Row`

to find the last row in the sheet with text in it. I want it to stop at the last row with text in it and move on to the next step. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you can work out how to use an if statement :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("W10", Range("W10").End(xlDown)) --Change it per requirement .....
For Each cell In r
 Debug.Print cell.Address --Your Code goes here I guess
Next
```